# ActionScript error when attempting call method within PHP file

Tags: php, actionscript

I have been following a flash tutorial online and I have created a simple flash interface. I am trying to retrieve data from my SQL database via a PHP file and display. I get the following error when I compile:

Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

```
var variables1:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
var varSend1:URLRequest = new URLRequest("databaseCall.php");
varSend1.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
varSend1.data = variables1;

var varLoader1:URLLoader=new URLLoader();
varLoader1.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
varLoader1.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,completeHandler1);

variables1.comType = "requestEntries";

varLoader1.load(varSend1);

function completeHandler1(event:Event):void{

if(event.target.data.returnBody ==""){
    gbOutput_txt.text = "No data coming through";
} else{
    gbOutput_txt.condenseWhite = true;
    gbOutput_txt.htmlText = "" +event.target.data.returnBody;
}
}
```

My code exactly matches the code that is used within the tutorial. I have modified the php file to simply return "" so the issue almost definitely lies within the action script...I think :S The compiler falls over when he completeHandler1 function is called. What do you think could be causing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sharing the original tutorial link might help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the completeHandler1 function before you attempt to use it anywhere else.

Here is your code modified to describe what I am talking about.

```
var variables1:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
var varSend1:URLRequest = new URLRequest("databaseCall.php");
varSend1.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
varSend1.data = variables1;

function completeHandler1(event:Event):void{

    if(event.target.data.returnBody ==""){
        gbOutput_txt.text = "No data coming through";
    } else{
        gbOutput_txt.condenseWhite = true;
        gbOutput_txt.htmlText = "" +event.target.data.returnBody;
    }

}

var varLoader1:URLLoader=new URLLoader();
varLoader1.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
varLoader1.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,completeHandler1);

variables1.comType = "requestEntries";

varLoader1.load(varSend1);
```

Give this a try and let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. That doesn't appear to have resolved the issue.

Here is the error message:

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at AS3_Adam_MySQL_Guestbook_fla::testimonials_1/completeHandler1()[AS3_Adam_MySQL_Guestbook_fla.testimonials_1::frame1:9]
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
 at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()

Comment: Ahhh, I think I know what the issue is.  the `gbOutput_txt` object referenced in the handler is null because it's not scoped properly.  Try altering how you reference that object by accessing it via the `event` object if possible.  You may have to do some debugging to figure out where in the event object, if it exists in it, that it can be referenced from.  Otherwise, you will have to create a custom event class that you can pass that object through to be used in your event handler.

Comment: Hi, Thanks again. I see what you mean. I will try again with your comments in mind. It baffles me though as the tutorial I have been watching has exactly the same code which compiles successfully in the video. strange. Thanks